# C++ : String to Character Array conversion (non-Ascii characters removed)

Tags: c++

I have a payload string, which I want to convert it into character array and then remove any non-ASCII characters from it. Here is my code:

```
bool invalidChar (char c) 
{  
    return !(c>=0 && c <256);   
} 
void stripUnicode(string &str) 
{ 
    str.erase(remove_if(str.begin(),str.end(), invalidChar), str.end());  
}
```

Payload_input is a string consisting of ascii and non-ascii characters:

```
 stripUnicode(Payload_input) ;

     char input[Payload_input.length()];
    strcpy(input,Payload_input.c_str());



    char chunk1[Payload_input.length()];
    int counter1=0;

for(counter1=0; counter1< size; counter1++)
{
        chunk1[counter1]=input[counter1];
}
```

Now, here is my string payload which I want to convert into char array:

```
--90B452BFFF3F395ABDC878D8BEDBD152
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploaddir"

language/2BB5B9330E/C/
--90B452BFFF3F395ABDC878D8BEDBD152
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"; filename="lottery[1]20110727082525.jpg"
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

JFIFddDucky<http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/<?xpacket begin="" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
```

In the above string, the few characters after  **Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary** appears in blocks (inside bloacks it is written 0001 etc) on linux terminal.

When I try to print the characters (cout << chunk1[counter1]) after stripping non-ASCII chararcters from the string then even some ASCII characters get omitted after line **Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary**.

Please point it out if there is something wrong with my code?

Comment: Just a smallthought: ASCII uses 7 bits. Maybe your char should be between 0 <= c < 128.

Comment: I want to cater all the extended ASCII characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that on Linux `char` is always in the range -128-127, so your `invalidChar` function will return `true` for all the chars not strictly ASCII. If you want to check for extended ASCII (0-255) then your function is useless: every `char` value is in the extended ASCII set; however, since `char` is signed you need to check for negative values.

Comment: `char` is not always signed. It is platform dependent.

Comment: right, but he talked about Linux. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Then do I need to change the range of ASCII character checking from -127 to 0 and from 0 to 127 ??

Comment: If you do, it will always return false, because every char is in that range. What is a non-ASCII character for you? what do you want to filter?

Comment: I just want to keep extended ASCII characters. By non-ASCII,I mean unicode characters...

Comment: Well, I just want to omit everything except Extended ASCII characters.

Comment: Yes, but every char is in the extended ASCII set.

Comment: A string is an array of chars. A char can have a value (on Linux) from -128 to 127. It is essentially a byte, if you don't care about the sign. The extended ASCII set is the standard ASCII (covering characters with values from 0 to 127) plus other characters in the range 128-255 (that if you take as signed char, is -128 to -1). So, your Payload_input already contains chars in the extended ASCII set, there is no way to filter it because by definition char (under most OS) covers all the extended ASCII set, nothing more and nothing less.

Comment: This means that the range 128-255 in standard ASCII basically corresponds to -128 to -1 of extended ASCII. For example 128=-128 and 255=-1.

Comment: no: standard ASCII is 0-127, extended is 0-255. char (in most OS) is a signed covering the range -128-+127. if you convert a signed char to an unsigned char, you get the range 0-255, that is the same of extended ASCII. So, positive values of char are in the range of standard ASCII, positive and negative will cover the whole extended ASCII

Comment: @Loghorn I have changed the char array to unsigned char array but still all the characters are not exactly the same as after line Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary.